# delete rows in 3 tables with on delete cascade

Tags: postgresql-9.1

For a relation 0..n between two tables (t1,t2), the mpd generates an intermediate table (t3) with two fk.
Let two constraints on the t3 table, each one with "on delete cascade", if I do:

```
delete from t1 where id1=$id1;
```

I want to delete all rows of the t3 which contain the fk id1 and all rows of the t2 which contain the fk id2.
Is it possible in one query ?
**Edit**: here are my tables:

```
create T1 (
id1 ...
...
CONSTRAINT pk_id1 PRIMARY KEY (id1) );

create T2 (
id2 ...
 ...
CONSTRAINT pk_id2 PRIMARY KEY (id2) );

create T3 (
id1 ...,
id2 ...,
CONSTRAINT pk_T3 PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2),
CONSTRAINT fk_T3_1 FOREIGN KEY (id2)
REFERENCES T2 (id2) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_T3_2 FOREIGN KEY (id1)
REFERENCES T1(id1) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

Comment: So you have two values `$id1, $id2` and you want to `DELETE from t1 where id1=$id1; DELETE from t2 where id2=$id2;` and all the related rows deleted from `t3` (which should be as you have cascade delete enabled)?

Comment: @ypercube: no, if I do delete from T1 where id1=$id1, then the row $id1 is deleted from T1 and the row $id1,$id2 from T3 BUT not $id2 from T2.

Comment: Which is the expected behaviour. You don't usually want to delete from `t2` as well because you may have another row in `t3` with `$id37, $id2`. What should happen to that row, deleted too?

Comment: By deleting id1, I expect that all rows in t3 containing id1 are deleted and, from this list, all rows in t2 also deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want these two statements inside a transaction:

```
DELETE FROM t2
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM t3
        WHERE t3.id2 = t2.id2
          AND t3.id1 = $id1
      ) ;

DELETE FROM t1
WHERE t1.id1 = $id1 ;
```

The cascading delete effects will take care of the rest. Not sure though what locking or isolation level will be best for this operation.

Note that if you specify `$id1 = 1`, the above will delete all rows from `t3` that have `id1 = 1` and some rows that do not. If for example, you have 3 rows in `t3` with `(1,5), (1,6), (1,7)`, the operation will delete them and also delete all rows that have `id2=5` or `id2=6` or `id2=7`. So rows with `(4,5), (8,5), (28,5), (2,6), (6,6), (40,7)` will also be deleted due to the cascading effects, when the three rows of `t2` (with `id2` `5,6,7` are deleted).

Comment: The 2nd query deletes from t3, too, due to the cascades.